# Adding dropdown box to WordPress menu

Tags: navigation, dropdown

I've created a navigation bar through the WordPress menu function. Is there a way to turn one of the links into a dropdown box, where selecting the box reveals all subpages?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Drag and drop one menu item to another]

Regarding front-end, this will work only if theme styling supports multilevel menus.